# Razor, partials and slow performance

Tags: performance, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have some complex pages that make use of many RenderPartial (from 13 up to 20).

I've found that those pages are taking from 400 - 800ms to render (that's just for the view rendering time. Action time is not included and it is not an issue).

There are no queries/anything else on the pages, they just render a pre-loaded model. If I "glue" all the partials on each page, I can cut those times to 1/4. That's a lot of time.

Precompiling the pages do not solve anything, as that only impacts the startup time of the page. But the generated code it's the same.

My question then is: Is there a way I can, via some external tool, to "replace" those RenderPartials with the actual code from the partial? Maybe I can even run that tool on deploy only. After all, those partials are only used on specific pages and they do not need to be accessed from other actions as standalone views...

Comment: sounds like a daunting task, but I doubt it will take you as much time as you think. I would just tough it out and start copy pasting.

Comment: The problem is that those modules may need to be updated (for sure) in the future, and I'm trying to not DRY.

Comment: Are you testing that in Release mode and debug="false"? View locations aren't cached if debug is enabled.

Comment: Yes. Release mode and view locations are cached (already checked that).